# Should I stain or paint my blotchy concrete?

Tags: concrete, staining, epoxy

The house I just moved into has a lot of white spots all over the concrete. I want to stain the whole slab to get it looking fresh and nice.  I had a couple contractors come out to help me resolve the issue.

One of them said a stain would work no problem, get it covered right up and looking nice.

The other said, no way that even after staining after a while its still going to continue to bleed through. Probably forever, because the concrete wasn't laid properly.  He said the best bet is an epoxy with a nice sealant. Even then there is no guarantee, but it has a better chance of working.

Who is correct?  Does anyone have any other advice on what I can do?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a power washer to remove some of the staining. If you haven't, it would be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the white spots are lime leaching up to the top. If the concrete stays wet, that is hard to stop. Sealing the concrete can help but it can wick up moisture from below too. I stained an interior slab and haven't had this problem but I think there is plastic below the slab. But personally I think your concrete looks fine. I would find another project to worry about.

Comment: Agree on all points. It's actually a somewhat appealing marbled appearance. Also, if that's your biggest concern at a new home, you've got it made. :)